# Using send with a method that accepts a block

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to accomplish this piece of metaprogramming in ruby

```
my_array = 1..10
method = :each

my_array.send(method) {|num| puts num }
```

which does not work. Does anybody know how to pass in the block dynamically? I have already tried:

```
my_array.send(:each, lambda{|num| puts num })
my_array.send(:each, Proc.new{|num| puts num })
```

but nothing worked. Thanks!

Comment: It turned out I tried to simplify my question too much. My real case was a bit more complicated and the reason why it was not working was my array was in fact ActiveRecord::Relation object. All I had to do was to_a. The case above of course works in ruby.

Comment: Good to know your problem solved, but you've completely confused me with `[1..10]`. I guess you were trying to define a range, but the syntax is `(1..10)`. What you defined above is an array of a single range and not an array of numbers from 1 to 10.

Comment: You're right. I should not do stuff in a hurry :-D. Updated.

Answer (score 8):

Your first snippet is perfectly fine, this should work:

```
(1..10).send(:each) { |num| puts(num) }
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. `my_array = [1..10]` from the question confused me, because it doesn't work for this `my_array` value. Don't know why, though. `[1..10].class` says `Array`, but what kind of array is that?

Comment: Crap, it's an array of a single range and everything works for it too.